# endless loop with SetInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I have this function. The purpose is to wait for an outside status to end before calling another function.

```
var renderEditClickWrapper = function( event )
{
    var wait = false;
    function waitForSavingDone(){
        if (options.dataStatusHandler.getStatus() == 'saving'){
            wait = setInterval( function(){
                waitForSavingDone();
            }, 800);
        }else{
            wait = false;
            call.renderEdit(event.data.name, event.data.rowId, event.data.parentId, event.data.options );
        }
    }

    if (!wait) waitForSavingDone();

    return false;
};
```

This works, however when the functions waits once, the function is called over and over.

I'm using jQuery as well.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: A `setInterval` runs repeatedly at the interval duration you provide. Because of this, the number of intervals running increases exponentially with the recursive calls. Either change it to `setTimeout`, or just create a single `setInterval` that is canceled with `clearInterval` when ready.

Comment: ...doesn't the API you're calling let you pass a callback function? That would be much nicer and more idiomatic than polling for the status to change.

Comment: @squint doh! I wanted to use setTimeout

Comment: It's my own library and saving is triggered by a background job itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one more alternative you may try:
Define a wait function as below:

```
 function wait(waitComplete, onWaitComplete){

    if (waitComplete()) {
       onWaitComplete();
       return true;
    }

    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('waiting...');
        wait(waitComplete, onWaitComplete);
    }, 800);

    return false;        
}
```

Event handler can use wait as below:

```
var renderEditClickWrapper = function( event )
{
   function isWaitComplete() { 
    return (options.dataStatusHandler.getStatus() != 'saving');
   }

   function onWaitComplete() {
     call.renderEdit(event.data.name, event.data.rowId, 
                     event.data.parentId, event.data.options);

   }
    wait(isWaitComplete, onWaitComplete);
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [clearInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval) method to cancel the interval function, instead of `wait = false`. And also you misunderstood the usage of interval functions. Do it like below:

```
var renderEditClickWrapper = function( event )
{

  function waitForSavingDone() {
    if (options.dataStatusHandler.getStatus() !== 'saving') {
      clearInterval(wait);
    }
  }

  var wait = setInterval(waitForSavingDone, 800);

  return false;
};
```

You should check the callback function as mentioned in the comments. It'll be more recommended if you use callback instead.